# View(model) vs View("viewName", model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

What is a basic difference between two overloads `View(model)` and `View("viewName", model)` if my action name is same as view name.

Which of those is prefered to use to make code more clear? Is there any performance difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that there shouldn't be any difference, the two methods are just overloads.

Here is the source from MVC3 codebase -

```
    protected internal ViewResult View() {
        return View(null /* viewName */, null /* masterName */, null /* model */);
    }

    protected internal ViewResult View(object model) {
        return View(null /* viewName */, null /* masterName */, model);
    }

    protected internal ViewResult View(string viewName) {
        return View(viewName, null /* masterName */, null /* model */);
    }

    protected internal ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName) {
        return View(viewName, masterName, null /* model */);
    }

    protected internal ViewResult View(string viewName, object model) {
        return View(viewName, null /* masterName */, model);
    }

    protected internal virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model) {
        if (model != null) {
            ViewData.Model = model;
        }

        return new ViewResult {
            ViewName = viewName,
            MasterName = masterName,
            ViewData = ViewData,
            TempData = TempData
        };
    }
```

And internally, if the `viewName` is not passed, MVC looks it up using the `ControllerContext`.